# War not include resources folder if run Maven Build from "run configurations" of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, war

I have a Maven project with some properties files under src/main/resources. If i run mvn clean war:war from the terminal, i can get a war with these files under WB-INF/classes/, so it's ok. If I run "Maven Build" directly from Run Configurations window of Eclipse, my War does not include the files under src/main/resources. How can I fix it?

This is my pom.xml relevant part (I think)

```
<build>
    <finalName>ProjectName</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>projectX.group.id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>projectX</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should **not** run `mvn clean war:war`. Always run `mvn clean verify` or `mvn verify`otherwise important steps are left out.

Comment: I've runned in "Run configurations" war:war (without clean) and it works! mvn clean verify said there are no issue, by the way. Thank you. I still cannot understand why "mvn clean war:war" was woriking if runned by CMD, but via "Run configurations"'s Eclipse it was not working...

Comment: Don't ever run `war:war`. It will just cause problems for you.

Comment: Ok Fabian, so how can I produce a war?

Comment: You run `mvn clean verify` to build a WAR. If you want it in your local repository, run `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Thank you. Maven is like a black hole to me, even if I'm trying to learn it...